# Intent <data> definition - host, pathPrefix?

Tags: android

I'm trying to capture a url like the following in an intent:

```
https://example.com/apple/orange?key=value
```

I've got the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<activity>
  <intent-filter>
    <action
      android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category
      android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category
      android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
      android:scheme="https"
      android:host="example.com"
      android:pathPrefix="/apple/orange.*" />

    ...
```

how should I modify this so the url gets captured?

Thanks

Comment: can you specify how you are trying to capture that in your intent.

Comment: ok updated for full activity def

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I used "path" and it should look like this:

```
android:path="/apple/orange"
```